# Image upload in WKWebView fails UnboundedNetworking Required client entitlement is missing

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm using a `WKWebView` which includes an image upload. The native `UIImagePickerController` shows up and the webview previews the selected image correctly, but when I press the upload button in the webview, the following error is shown and the upload fails:

```
[assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=3 "Required client entitlement is missing" UserInfo={RBSAssertionAttribute=<RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.webkit" name:"UnboundedNetworking" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Required client entitlement is missing}>
[ProcessSuspension] 0x1122f5fc0 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS UnboundedNetworking assertion 'WebKit uploads' for process with PID 35109, error: Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=3 "Required client entitlement is missing" UserInfo={RBSAssertionAttribute=<RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.webkit" name:"UnboundedNetworking" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Required client entitlement is missing}
```

I found a couple of people facing the same issue in the Apple developer forums, but no solution so far. The image upload itself works, as it's successful when testing directly in Safari on the iPhone.

These are the things I already tried without success:

- Granted permission for full PhotoLibrary access
- Searched for any entitlements that might be available, but found nothing (except entitlements that are available on MacOS but not iOS)
- Tried to add the MacOS entitlements but also not working

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any solution? Same problem here

Comment: Any Solution @Hannes ? Same Problem here